# Ionic v2 problems with cards

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, cross-platform, ionic-view

This is will be two parts or two questions, I have researched this a lot over the past few days and I can not find an answer, so if I missed it and it is in the docs or somewhere else please link me.

One, I am trying to get a background imagine card to show an image but when I build the app, there is a problem with the image and it will not display, any ideas on how to fix?

Question two, is there a way to make a card clickable and lead to another view. I have created the view but I want to use the card to link to send the user to the page when selecting three things.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: please post your code with your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as shown below.

Here is the [**working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rk3lAh?p=preview)

*app/home.page.html*

```
<ion-card (click)="user()">
  <ion-card-header>
    Header
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/rkedK1U.jpg" alt="Login">
    This is my image card
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

*app/home.page.ts*

```
 user(): void {
    this.navCtrl.push(UserPage);
  }
```

*Clickable Image Card:*

[image]

Comment: is there a a max resolution for the images?

Comment: No, you can set it as you wish.But always good if you design it for multiple resolutions.see this too:http://uxmovement.com/mobile/6-tips-on-designing-graphics-for-mobile-devices/